# SQL Server 2005 - get items count existing in time interval by hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Sorry for maybe bad title name but it's very hard to explain. So I will try it here again.
I have records with columns [startdatetime] [enddatetime]. I need to know in which hours those record exists and count this for every hour.

Example:

```
Id   Start               End
1    2013-01-01 15:00    2013-01-01 18:00
2    2013-01-01 13:00    2013-01-01 17:00
3    2013-01-01 10:00    2013-01-01 19:00
```

Result should be:

```
Time                 Qty 
2013-01-01 10:00      1 
2013-01-01 11:00      1 
2013-01-01 12:00      1 
2013-01-01 13:00      2 
2013-01-01 14:00      2 
2013-01-01 15:00      3 
2013-01-01 16:00      3 
2013-01-01 17:00      2 
2013-01-01 18:00      1 
2013-01-01 19:00      0
```

This should be computed for long time period, maybe months. This example is with one day just for make it easy to understand.

I have really no idea how to achieve this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the messy `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags, either!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn this problem into a discrete one.
Think of hours as time segments of length 1.
Then N consecutive hours are a time segment of length N.

Create a table with a datetime column.
Insert there all hours (they will not be that many).
Insert there e.g. their start times (the end time can
be implied from the start time).

Then join from your table T to this new table based on 
some custom function which you write named **hour_overlap**.

This **hour_overlap** function should just check if a 
time segment (sequence of several consecutive hours)
contains an hour. Should be a trivial one.

Alternatively, you can turn hours into integers
if you know up-front the overall/full time interval
(say from 1/1/2006 onwards). And still use this idea of
an **hour_overlap** function but implement it even more
easily as you will have to deal with integers only.